# PHP - как присвоить значение в массиве

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => KNECHT
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => Фильтр топл.AUDI/VW/SEAT
            [ident] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => MAHLE 
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => Топливный фильтр
            [ident] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => METAL LEVE
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => Топливный фильтр
            [ident] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => KNECHT
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => 
            [ident] => 25446040
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => MAHLE 
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => 
            [ident] => 47847542
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => PATRON
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => 
            [ident] => 147622787
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [manufacturer] => VAG
            [article] => KL2
            [name] => 
            [ident] => 136414413
        )

)
```

Как лучше собрать новый массив, в котором если совпадают значения ключей `[manufacturer]`  например `[0]  [manufacturer]=>KNECHT` и  `[3] [manufacturer]=>KNECHT` но при этом в  `[0] [manufacturer]=>KNECHT` не заполнено значение ключа `[ident] =>` ,присвоить значение `[ident] => 25446040`  из массива `[3]`. Т.е. если manufacturer  совпадают то присвоить такой же ident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй как-нибудь так. Можно сделать лучше, но это первое, что пришло в голову :)

Для присвоения значений в новый массив просто скопируем существующий и его отредачим. Ну и в цикле уже становится без разницы по какому массиву пробегаться по `$newArray` или по `$firstArray`. Главное чтобы присвоение было в `$newArray`.

```
$newArray = $firstArray;
$manufacturers = [];
$idents = [];
foreach ($firstArray as $key=>$item){
    if(in_array($item['manufacturer'], $manufacturers)){
        $keyVar = array_search($item['manufacturer'], $manufacturers);
        if(empty($idents[$keyVar])){
            $newArray[$keyVar]['ident'] = $item['ident'];
        }
    }else{
        $manufacturers[$key] = $item['manufacturer'];
        $idents[$key] = $item['ident'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как собрать новый массив ? С новыми значениями.

Comment: @Андрей именно новый. Сейчас исправлю ответ

Comment: Спасибище  огромное. Все заработало!

Comment: @Андрей очень хорошо. Отметьте тогда ответ, чтобы в дальнейшем люди понимали, что он верный